# How to turn in student work e.g assignments and questions

Tags: ios, google-classroom

We are working on an iOS app for the iPad, with Google Classroom integration.
What we want to achieve is to integrate Classroom in such a manner, that students can read their Classroom Courses, Classroom Work Items and Classroom announcements. 
We also want to allow students to work on their assignments and/or questions and turn in their assignments or questions, with the included answers of the students. We want this to be solely done in the iOS app.

Well, recently we discovered that there is no proper way to implement turning in an assignment with all the necessary answers/replies. We build a great custom interface for viewing the Classroom Courses and Assignments/Questions, but right now we’re stuck on implementing the possibility to work on assignments/questions and turn in the assignments/questions as a student.

With this info, we’re asking for some advice how to move forward right now. What are we supposed to do? Is answering to assignments with the work of a student even supported right now?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the [turnIn API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn)? While I'm not an iOS developer, it seems there are libraries for both Swift and Objective-C (https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/ios) as well. All that's needed are the IDs for the Course, CourseWork and the Submission to use the endpoint.